# Match string by regex token and replace with text inside tokens in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a user input field in html, and I want to grab text that is tagged by characters, and then replace the text inside of the tags with a html span tags. Example of text in an html element:

@"this is a text tag" inside of an html element, the tag is anything starting with an '@' character followed by a quotation character (") and closed by a quotation character. So this is @"also a tag".

```
I want to convert  @"this is a text tag" to <span>this is a text tag</span> 
and @"also a tag" become <span>also a tag</span>
```

Here's the code I started with but I'm a bit lost:

```
        let text = htmlElement.textContent;
        let regex = /@"(.*?)"/g;
        let match = text.replace(regex, `<span>/*the text in the tag here*/</span>`);
        console.log(match);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your captured group will contain the text inside the `"`s, so all you need to do is put the captured group inside the `<span></span>` with `$1`:

```js
const replacedText = htmlElement.textContent.replace(
  /@"([^"]+)"/g,
  `<span>$1</span>`
);
console.log(replacedText);
```

```html
<div id="htmlElement">I want to convert  @"this is a text tag" !
and @"also a tag" become</div>
```

Note that you can use a negative character set (`[^"]+`) instead of `.*?` to make the regular expression a bit more efficient.